# Java regex removing last value unexpectedly

Tags: java, regex

I have a paragraph as follows (This is an example paragraph- in my other samples the words and letters remain the same and only the numbers change):

```
blablabla

Reflux Table - Day1 
 Total Upright Supine Meal PostPr Cough
 Duration of Period  (d,hh: mm) 23:13 14:05 09:08 00:48 05:59 00:15
Number of Refluxes 56 56 0 1 32 1
Number of Long Refluxes>5  (min) 1 1 0 0 0 0
Duration of longest reflux (min) 5 5 0 0 4 1
Time pH <4  (min) 66 66 0 0 40 1
Fraction Time pH <4  (%) 4.8 0.0 11.3 3.6

some more text blablaotherStuff
```

I want to extract the following paragraph

```
Reflux Table - Day1 
 Total Upright Supine Meal PostPr Cough
 Duration of Period  (d,hh: mm) 23:13 14:05 09:08 00:48 05:59 00:15
Number of Refluxes 56 56 0 1 32 1
Number of Long Refluxes>5  (min) 1 1 0 0 0 0
Duration of longest reflux (min) 5 5 0 0 4 1
Time pH <4  (min) 66 66 0 0 40 1
Fraction Time pH <4  (%) 4.8 0.0 11.3 3.6
```

To do this I have the following code:

```
Pattern ReflDay1_pattern = Pattern.compile("Reflux Table - Day1 .*?Fraction Time[^\n]*",Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcherReflDay1_pattern = ReflDay1_pattern.matcher(s);
ArrayList<String> ReflDay1_arr = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            while (matcherReflDay1_pattern.find()) {
        ReflDay1_arr.add(matcherReflDay1_pattern.group(0)); 
        System.out.println("matcherReflDay1_pattern.group(0)"+matcherReflDay1_pattern.group(0));
                                                 }
            } 

        catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

However this result chops off the last value so that I lose the '3.6'. This happens in any paragraph I try. How can I make sure it is included- is it the regex (I have tested the regex and it does extract what it should be extracting including the value 3.6)?

```
Reflux Table - Day1 
 Total Upright Supine Meal PostPr Cough
 Duration of Period  (d,hh: mm) 23:13 14:05 09:08 00:48 05:59 00:15
Number of Refluxes 56 56 0 1 32 1
Number of Long Refluxes>5  (min) 1 1 0 0 0 0
Duration of longest reflux (min) 5 5 0 0 4 1
Time pH <4  (min) 66 66 0 0 40 1
Fraction Time pH <4  (%) 4.8 0.0 11.3
```

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment.

Comment: can you tell how are you passing string in matcher method i mean how to construct string from the data you are showing, i believe it has delimiters .. right?

Comment: You code is work man

Comment: Aha just above the code I found this line: s=s.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d+|n\\/a)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+|n\\/a)", "$1"); which I think is the culprit- I think the idea was to get rid of whitespace at the end of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conjecture is that the line endings are actually `"\r\n"` (Windows) but just that 3.6 was written as `"\n 3.6"` or such. Notepad would show it as being on the same line.

```
Pattern ReflDay1_pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "Reflux Table - Day1 .*?Fraction Time[^\r\n]*\n[^\r\n]*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Using `\r` also prevents this character to trail the string.

```
String g = matcherReflDay1_pattern.group(0).replaceAll("\r?\n", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this from your code snippet and it works great!!!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\NPGM81B\\Desktop\\text.txt");
        Pattern ReflDay1_pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "Reflux Table - Day1 .*?Fraction Time[^\n]*", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcherReflDay1_pattern = ReflDay1_pattern.matcher(getStringFromInputStream(f));
        ArrayList<String> ReflDay1_arr = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            while (matcherReflDay1_pattern.find()) {
                ReflDay1_arr.add(matcherReflDay1_pattern.group(0));
                System.out.println("matcherReflDay1_pattern.group(0)   : "
                        + matcherReflDay1_pattern.group(0));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // convert InputStream to String
    private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }


}

text.txt
-------------
Reflux Table - Day1 
 Total Upright Supine Meal PostPr Cough
 Duration of Period  (d,hh: mm) 23:13 14:05 09:08 00:48 05:59 00:15
Number of Refluxes 56 56 0 1 32 1
Number of Long Refluxes>5  (min) 1 1 0 0 0 0
Duration of longest reflux (min) 5 5 0 0 4 1
Time pH <4  (min) 66 66 0 0 40 1
Fraction Time pH <4  (%) 4.8 0.0 11.3 3.6
```